# How to hide keyboard while keeping cursor in swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I am making a calculator and using my own keypad and i want there to be no keyboard that pops up when the textview is activated but i want the user to be able to move the cursor around. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you should try  to use a `UILabel` instead of `UITextField`

Comment: @ronan but then there would be no cursor, right? sorry I'm new to iOS I've only done android before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the `inputView` for the textfield to custom UIView. Something like below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
let customView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTextField.inputView = customView
}
```

Comment: inputView supposedly is device keyboard, but we replace it with custom UIView. Thats it.

Comment: also similar thing if want to change keyboard to datepicker, we can use the inputView